# Multiple JPanels one of top of the other

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

Been trying to make 4 `JPanel`s two on top and other 2 on the bottom and manipulate each independently of each other inputing text etc...beginner with java so if anybody can help me out that would be awesome. I posted another question before but now I am stuck again. lol

```
package project2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // specifies how components are arranged
import javax.swing.JFrame; // provides basic window features
import javax.swing.JLabel; // displays text and images
import javax.swing.JPanel; // Displays a Panel
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; // common constants used with Swing
import javax.swing.Icon; // interface used to manipulate images
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; // loads images
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class GUI 
  {
private JPanel Checks; //Panel to Hold Checks
private JPanel Transactions;
private JPanel History;
private JPanel Graphics;
private JLabel CLabel;

public void displayGUI()
 {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(
                        new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
     contentPane.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    Checks = getPanel(Color.YELLOW.darker().darker());
    Transactions = getPanel(Color.RED);
    History = getPanel(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());
    Graphics = getPanel(Color.MAGENTA);
    CLabel = new JLabel("Label with on red text");


    contentPane.add(Checks);
    contentPane.add(Transactions);
    contentPane.add(History);
    contentPane.add(Graphics);

    frame.setSize(1400,690); //set frame size
    frame.setVisible(true); //display frame

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);



     }
     private JPanel getPanel(Color bColor) {
     JPanel panel = new JPanel();

     panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setBackground(bColor);

    return panel;
     }
```

**Expected Output :**

[image: output]

Comment: May you please elaborate, as to what you set out to perform, and what exactly never pan out !!! A small sketch, of exactly what the expected output should look like, would be highly welcomed :-) Looking at your previous post, it appears you need a `GridLayout`

Comment: added to the original post, but ill add it here too hehe http://s14.postimg.org/es3uu8sld/Untitled.png

Comment: now I need to add text to it. Posting this here for someone in the future that needs it. am editing my own code with what I have right now :)

Comment: `frame.pack() and frame.set.Visible()` should be the last lines, after adding all the components to the frame, so the frame realizes it's size before setting itself to visible. And please learn Java Naming Conventions, data members always use Camel Notation, first word small and other words with Capitalized literal, like `myVariableName` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this answer, and see if you need this or something else. Do let us know, we might try to add a bit more deeper.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 9/30/13
 * Time: 6:02 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class UTBInCheck {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    private JPanel topLeftPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;
    private JTextArea infoArea;
    private JScrollPane infoScroller;
    private JTextField payOrderField;
    private JTextField amountField;
    private JButton orderSubmitButton;
    private JButton orderClearButton;
    private JPanel topRightPanel;
    private JTextArea recentTransArea;
    private JScrollPane recentTransScroller;
    private JButton updateButton;
    private JPanel bottomLeftPanel;
    private JTextField atmWithdrawalField;
    private JTextField atmDepositField;
    private JTextField directDepositField;
    private JTextField wireTransferField;
    private JTextField electronicBillField;
    private JTextField bankFeeField;
    private JButton etSubmitButton;
    private JButton etClearButton;
    private JPanel bottomRightPanel;

    private Random random;
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private int checkNumber;

    public UTBInCheck() {
        random = new Random();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        checkNumber = 811;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("University of Texas at Brownsville");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = getPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, GAP, GAP));
        topLeftPanel = getPanel();
        setTopLeftPanel(topLeftPanel);
        topRightPanel = getPanel();
        setTopRightPanel(topRightPanel);
        bottomLeftPanel = getPanel();
        setBottomLeftPanel(bottomLeftPanel);
        bottomRightPanel = getPanel();

        contentPane.add(topLeftPanel);
        contentPane.add(topRightPanel);
        contentPane.add(bottomLeftPanel);
        contentPane.add(bottomRightPanel);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setTopLeftPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));

        JPanel topPanel = getPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel universityLabel = getLabel("University of Texas at Brownsville");
        addComp(topPanel, universityLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.2,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);
        JLabel checkNumberLabel = getLabel("Check Number : " + checkNumber);
        addComp(topPanel, checkNumberLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.2,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST);

        infoArea = new JTextArea(5, 10);
        infoArea.setLineWrap(true);
        infoArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        infoScroller = new JScrollPane();
        infoScroller.setViewportView(infoArea);
        addComp(topPanel, infoScroller, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.4,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

        JPanel centerPanel = getPanel();
        centerPanel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, GAP, GAP));
        JLabel payOrderLabel = getLabel("Pay to the order of : ");
        payOrderField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel amountLabel = getLabel("Amount : ");
        amountField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel chrisBankLabel = getLabel("Cris' Bank");
        JPanel buttonPanel = getPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, GAP, GAP));
        orderSubmitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        orderClearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonPanel.add(orderSubmitButton);
        buttonPanel.add(orderClearButton);

        centerPanel.add(payOrderLabel);
        centerPanel.add(payOrderField);
        centerPanel.add(amountLabel);
        centerPanel.add(amountField);
        centerPanel.add(chrisBankLabel);
        centerPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        addComp(topPanel, centerPanel, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1.0, 0.4,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);

        panel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp,
                         int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight,
                         double weightx, double weighty, int fill, int anchor) {
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        gbc.fill = fill;
        gbc.anchor = anchor;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    private void setTopRightPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Recent Transactions"));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));

        recentTransArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        recentTransArea.setLineWrap(true);
        recentTransArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        recentTransScroller = new JScrollPane();
        recentTransScroller.setViewportView(recentTransArea);

        JPanel buttonPanel = getPanel();
        updateButton = new JButton("Update");
        buttonPanel.add(updateButton);

        panel.add(recentTransScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void setBottomLeftPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Electronic Transactions"));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, GAP, GAP));

        JLabel atmWithdrawLabel = getLabel("ATM Withdrawals : ");
        atmWithdrawalField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel atmdepositLabel = getLabel("ATM Deposit : ");
        atmDepositField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel directDepositLabel = getLabel("Direct Deposit : ");
        directDepositField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel wireTransferLabel = getLabel("Wire Transfers : ");
        wireTransferField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel electronicBillLabel = getLabel("Electronic Bills : ");
        electronicBillField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel bankFeeLabel = getLabel("Bank Fees : ");
        bankFeeField = new JTextField(10);

        JPanel buttonPanel = getPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, GAP, GAP));
        etSubmitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        etClearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonPanel.add(etSubmitButton);
        buttonPanel.add(etClearButton);

        panel.add(atmWithdrawLabel);
        panel.add(atmWithdrawalField);
        panel.add(atmdepositLabel);
        panel.add(atmDepositField);
        panel.add(directDepositLabel);
        panel.add(directDepositField);
        panel.add(wireTransferLabel);
        panel.add(wireTransferField);
        panel.add(electronicBillLabel);
        panel.add(electronicBillField);
        panel.add(bankFeeLabel);
        panel.add(bankFeeField);
        //Adding JPanel just to occupy space;
        panel.add(getPanel());
        panel.add(buttonPanel);
    }

    private JLabel getLabel(String text) {
        return (new JLabel(text, JLabel.LEFT));
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(getRandomColor());
        /*panel.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));*/

        return panel;
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return (new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                          random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new UTBInCheck().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: gridlayoutexample]

Comment: Thank you, that is what I want. I need to add info on there. Like a check and balance etc. I am heading to work right now(for 4 hours) ill be back. I need to finish this project by Thursday. I will also like to know how it was done exactly so if you dont mind putting comments so i can understand and not have to ask later. if you can/want. if not its ok. thanks again for the help nice cow :P hehe

Comment: Hope you be able to understand well, as to what is happening now inside the code, with these added comments. Though always feel free to ask anything, if something or everything is still unclear :-) I would be happy to help. Though I might go to sleep in some time, so will try to answer you tomorrow, as soon as I come in front of my computer :-)

Comment: @IcE cOw now i need to add text to it

Comment: @Ice cOw http://oi40.tinypic.com/246jqq0.jpg  I wish I knew more about this , not knowing is discouraging and frustrating. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @IcE cOw I did it! ok now..the button is all towards the bottom lol I was going to tell you that am using the colors for myself. so i would not get them confused. but i really just want them whiteish and yellowish for the (checks). THANKS :D http://oi44.tinypic.com/28i20q0.jpg my question now being, how do i set the "perimeters" for the botton and the text area.. :S

Comment: I don't know if you would like my email or if its even legal to post it here, so we can chat and ill show you what i have? hope you dont mind me asking that question, if you prefer here thats all right. just  takes a while >.< lol

Comment: @Rafa579 : What is this thingy at the TopLeftPanel, where __"Cristian Torres"__ is written, is this a `JTextArea`. If yeah, give me 15 mins, to make that adjustment too :-) Hope the output so far is to your liking :-)

Comment: @ice cow it is, thank you very much! :) its emulating a check. it will extract the information from the user after putting an account number (password doesnt matter) (everything stored in a .txt file :)